# jQuery xml cross domain data parsing fail in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, facebook

I'm new to jQuery and would like to parse an xml document.
So far, I've been doing:

```
$.ajax({
        url: xmlUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        crossDomain: true,
        error: function(){                          
        alert('Error loading XML document'); 
        }, 
        success: function(xml) {
       }
});
```

However, I always get the error message in ie8.

Here is the xmlUrl address which I want to parse.

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=MyUrl

With really no luck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid IE 8 does not support [Crss Origin requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), hence does not allow the cross-domain request (unless you do not setup the browser itself).

As the service you are trying to use does not use any client's data, you can setup a proxy - simple PHP script, that retrieves the url and output (via curl or file_get_contents if allow_url_fopen is enabled), and use ajax without the crossdomain.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I followed your advice and wrote a simple PHP script to retrieves the url and output.

In front-end I use ajax and it is work in ie8. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Facebook JavaScript SDK (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), as it will take care of that issue for you.  Also the method of using the restserver is deprecated, you can use the new SDK to call into the Graph API.

Comment: Did you mean this?'https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=myurl' for comment number and 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=myurl' for like numbers?